# AngularJS Form Mail - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm trying to send an email from my AngularJS website with the following configuration:

Contact.index.html:

```
<form  name="userForm"  class="well form-search">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Name" required >
    <input type="email" ng-model="email" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Email" required >
    <input type="text" ng-model="message" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Message" required >
    <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="formsubmit(userForm.$valid)"  ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit </button>
</form>
<pre ng-model="result">
    {{result}}
</pre>
```

Contact.controller.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('core').controller('ContactController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$window',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $http, $window) {
        $scope.url = '../../resources/submit.php';
        $scope.formsubmit = function(isValid) {
            if (isValid) {
                $http.post($scope.url, {"name": $scope.name, "email": 'admin@website.com', "message": $scope.message}).
                        success(function(data, status) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                            $scope.result = data;
                        })
            }else{
                  alert('Form is not valid');
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Submit.php:

```
<?php
    $post_date = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($post_date);

    //print the values
    echo "Name : ".$data->name."\n";
    echo "Email : ".$data->email."\n";
    echo "Message : ".$data->message."\n";
?>
```

I'm receiving the following error when viewing my site console:

> [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     (anonymous function)
>   (submit.php:1)

I've tried wrapping my php file in the following (didn't help)

> angular.callbacks._0 ( { })

and my file structure looks as follows:

```
dist/
├── bower_components
│   ├── ...
├── css
│   └── app.css
├── index.html
├── js
│   └── app.js
└── resources
    ├── ...
    └── submit.php
```

Comment: Is the PHP code actually executed on the server, or just returned as plain text? How do you serve your PHP files?

Comment: This is all running on a localhost web server.

Comment: What do you see if you navigate directly to the PHP file in your browser?

Comment: If I visit http://localhost:8000/resources/action.php the file downloads

Comment: Well, then the PHP is not executed, but the server is serving the file contents directly. Look into a web server with a PHP runtime. XAMPP may be a good starting point.

Comment: If i visit the php file on my server, I get the following error:
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128882/discussion-between-trent-and-timo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection, the error I was receiving:

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (anonymous function) (submit.php:1)
```

was a result of trying to test my PHP scripts on a local server which does not support PHP.

For anyone experiencing this same issue, please try uploading your website files to a PHP-enabled server for testing.